# php imap_search since problem

Tags: php, imap

I am using the following code to fetch all mails since 1 day less -

```
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime ("-1 days"));
$searchQuery = 'SINCE "'.$yesterday.'"';

if($this->open($folder)) {
    $imap_search = imap_search($this->_imap, $searchQuery);
}
```

This works fine on my dev windows machine but when i put it on the test production server it doesn't work. I have even tried ALL as the search parameter but it does not seem to fetch anything. The connection to the mail account (the $this->_imap object) seems to be fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there different PHP versions running on the 2 servers?

Comment: yes.. php 5.2.8 on the windows system and 5.2.1 on the linux server...

Comment: i think this is a segmentation fault issue. http://bugs.php.net/48619. Will continue debugging and post if i find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since noone else answered, I will put it as a wiki for whoever comes in after me looking for the same issue. The problem I faced was with the php version used on the server (5.2.1). Seems like it has a [bug](http://bugs.php.net/48619) which causes it to segfault. Upgrading the php version fixed the issue for me.

Comment: What is result? Did you get error or imap_search selected all dates ?